# c++ fopen() returning a NULL pointer when I try using a char array or pointer

Tags: c, file, fopen

I'm attempting to open a file with fopen and storing it into a FILE*.

The code I have is as follows:

```
    char path[300];

    printf("File name: ");

    fgets(path, 300, stdin);
    
    
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen(path, "r");

    
    if (fp == NULL) {

    printf("file does not exist\n");

    }
```

When I run the above code, I get a file not found error; however, when I hardcode the file name:

```
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
```

The code works as intended.
I think the issue might have something to do with the data type since fopen requires a const char* for it's parameter. I've tried using char*'s but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's much simpler than that. When you use `fgets` the newline character at the end of the line gets included in the char array. That newline is then messing up your attempt to open the file.

Incidentally `fopen` does not require a `const char*` parameter. It requires a parameter which can be **converted** to a `const char*`. That includes `char*` as well as `char []`.

Comment: `std::getline` will discard the line ending for you. And it uses `std::string` which will resize itself if the user inputs a path of 300 or more characters.

Comment: @user4581301, no need to confuse a beginner with c++ when he is clearly programming in c

Comment: @HAL I don't follow the C tag, so if I'm here, the question was tagged C++. It's kind-of negligent to not point out the simplest way to solve the problem may be to use a C++ feature.